# Create <div> of Custom shapes to design RFM segmentation

Tags: html, css, reactjs

So RFM segmentation looks like this https://www.putler.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/rfm-grid.png

I want to recreate it in html where each blocks repesents one segment. I tried doing it as [1,1] block but as I want to create a hover effect. Mutiple blocks need to be combined together to have one overall effect.

I tried doing it with div but not able to create the hover effect 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/X1C1t.png

Here is the React code

```
                                  <div class="rfmBox">
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div>5</div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFC9CE" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEDB7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E7F7BA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E7F7BA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E0ECBC" }} />
                </div>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div>4</div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEDB7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEDB7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E7F7BA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E7F7BA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#E7F7BA" }} />
                </div>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div>3</div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEDB7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEDB7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#9AF4E7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#C1FFFA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#C1FFFA" }} />
                </div>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div>2</div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#CFD8E4" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#F1F2F4" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#B9E0E7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#C1FFFA" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#C1FFFA" }} />
                </div>
                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#CFD8E4" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#CFD8E4" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#B9E0E7" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#C0ECFD" }} />
                    <div style={{ backgroundColor: "#FFEEEE" }} />
                </div>

                <div class="flex-container">
                    <div />
                    <div>1</div>
                    <div>2</div>
                    <div>3</div>
                    <div>4</div>
                    <div>5</div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried updating the z-index, so the element below an element does not overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `display: grid;` you can create only one `<div>` by area, and then for each area place it as you wish using `grid-column` and `grid-row` css properties.

Just add some `position: relative` and `z-index` and that's it !

I made a codepen where I tried to do the same thing that what you want : https://codepen.io/loic/pen/ZZePXd

(I did setup any React code, as I solved your issue with only html and css).

Hope it made the trick ;)

Comment: Super. Just one issue, while hovering on 2 it should not cover the part of 1. Can that be done ?

Comment: On my browser (chrome) hovering 2 do not cover the part of 1. Otherwise, just play with z-index and it should be ok

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is to add position: relative; on the divs and a z-index on hover.

here is a code sandbox that functions similar but is totally ugly. 
https://codesandbox.io/embed/oqwlvr7229?fontsize=14

EDIT: Read your issue wrong. here is an update. similar solution but reflects your problem closer.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/oqwlvr7229?fontsize=14